# Model in another module

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I'd like use second module for entity classes, and I use Spring Data Jpa.
This is my Entity classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @Column(name = "last_updated")
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

... getters and setters.
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

... getters and setters.
```

And I created Repository:

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {}
```

I use my entity this:

```
Event event = new Event();
event.setTitle("Some title");
event.setDescription("Some description");
event.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
event.setLastUpdated(LocalDateTime.now());
eventRepository.save(event);
```

When entity classes and repository in one Spring boot project it works ok. But I created separate library and moved entity there. I added dependense in first project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.library.groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>my.library.artefactId</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

And IDEA don't say me about any problems, but if I run project I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.asdfasdsdaf.sadfas.model.Event
    at
```

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When entity classes are not placed in the main application package or its sub-packages, we can use **@EntityScan**.
This will tell Spring where to find entities used in our application.
You should be aware that using @EntityScan will disable Spring Boot auto-configuration scanning for entities.